# Performance of separate LINQ2SQL selects with group and join on two indexed tables vs. one combined select

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to retrieve records from a table (tab_activities), grouped by ID, only the latest record of each group determined by date.
Of those latest records I only need those with a specific property (finished) not yet set.
In the end i have to crosscheck if any activities are also registered in a blacklist (tab_flaggedActivities) and then do something with all activities not finished and not flagged.

Both tables have indexes on the id.
The id is not the primary key, obviously.

I am not sure if what I am doing is the most performant way of setting up this select.
Is it better to have those individual selects combined in one select? If yes, how would I do that?

```
// Retrieve only the latest activity entry of each known activity-ID
var latestActivityRecords = from activity in dc.tab_activities
                            where activity.dateRegistered > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-MaxAge)
                            group activity by activity.id
                            into groups
                            select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.dateRegistered).First();

// Filter activities that are not finished
var unfinishedActivityRecords = from activity in latestActivityRecords
                                where !activity.finished
                                select activity;

// Check if any of those are in blacklist (different table)
var flaggedActivityRecords = from activity in unfinishedActivityRecords
                             join flaggedActivity in dc.tab_flaggedActivities 
                             on activity.id equals flaggedActivity.id
                             select activity;

if (unfinishedActivities != null)
{
    // Do something with all unfinished / unflagged activities 
    foreach (var activityRecord in unfinishedActivityRecords)
    {
        if (!flaggedActivityRecords.Any(p => p.id == activityRecord.id))
        {
            DoSomething(activityRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing does combine the queries into a single query before sending to the database. Check the types of `latestActivityRecords` & `unfinishedActivityRecords`. Since you are doing nothing to cause the query to execute, execution is deferred until the iteration in the `foreach` and the `if` with the `Any` test. However, because the `Any` test is in a loop, you should execute the `flaggedActivityRecords` once in the assigment by adding a `.ToList()` or, depending on size, perhaps `.Select(a => a.id).ToHashSet()` (in which case, you might as well execute `unfinishedActivityRecords`).

Comment: What is `unfinishedActivities`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you meant was combining the `if` `Any` test with the queries, you can reverse the meaning of the last query and just loop over the result, executing the filtering on the database server:

```
var unflaggedActivityRecords = from activity in unfinishedActivityRecords
                               where !dc.tab_flaggedActivities.Select(fa => fa.id).Contains(activity.id)
                               select activity;

if (unfinishedActivities != null) {
    // Do something with all unfinished / unflagged activities 
    foreach (var activityRecord in unflaggedActivityRecords) {
        DoSomething(activityRecord);
    }
}
```